# 3 plants per pots - 6 pots per treatment - replicates and pseudoreplicates

Tags: experiment-design, randomized-tests

I'm currently working on the statistical evaluation of an experiment. Certain products have been tested towards their influence on plant growth.

**Description**

There are 12 treatments in total and each treatment was applied on 6 pots (replicate?). In each pot, 3 plants were grown (3 pseudoreplicates?). By the end of the experiment, some plants have died. This was more severe in some treatments than in others, meaning that there is for example one treatment with only one "3 plant pot" and five pots containing only one plant.

*The plants were grown in a randomized block design with treatments used for blocking.*

What should be used for statistical analysis?

The biomass of the whole pot whereas pots with less than 3 plants will be omitted?

Or the mean biomass of each pot? (total biomass per pot divided by the number of plants per pot)

Unfortunately I don't have the data for each and every plant. I only have the biomass of each pot and the number of plants by the end of the experiment.

Comment: How many pots altogether in the randomized block design? (Fewer than 6(12)=72, I suppose.)

Comment: If some treatments killed the plants, this is probably an important point to consider.  Maybe the total biomass of each pot and not exclude any results?